# How do you prevent problems with a button being pressed more than once?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, windowed

In a windowed programming environment, a user may click a button more than once if they do not immediately see something happen.

How do you stop the code behind the button being executed more than once in this situation?

Comment: Have you tried to disable the button as the first action that occurs when het user clicks the button? (And of course the last action of the button-click should be to enable the button again.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to disabling the button, a wait cursor will visually help the user to see that something is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the button until the action is complete